# convenient, predictable entropy generator

Tags: unix

I am writing test cases for a high performance data compression system. (well, not exactly it, but for the testing purposes it can be described as this)

For the test i have to generate 500GB~3TB of random files in a directory.

For now i am using `/dev/urandom` but that has the problem of being, well, random.

Nothing guarantees that i won't get several files full of zeros one time, and a change to the algo that should have reflected negatively in efficiency will show up as high efficient.

Is there a way to generate that amount of random data, without having to store that permanently, and having it be predictable?

something like: seed one function, generate the data, inspect the data, commit the seed, trust that you will get the same generated data every time.

i know can seed urandom, but it does not work to generate the same data every time as i hoped for.

is there anything like the above with the convenience on UNIX that /dev/urandom provides?

Comment: Here at RSAC this week, there is a vendor that sells a board that will seed urandom with quantum-ly verified truly random data. I'm not sure that's what you are looking for though ...

Comment: If its predictable, wouldn't it be not really enthropic?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a linear congruence PRNG (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Basically they are recurrence relations, where the output at each step serves as the seed for the next step:

X_{n+1} = (a*X_n + c) mod m

The numbers a, X_0, c and m should be chosen so that they maximize the length of the sequence before repetition occurs.  The feature that is nice for you is that given the same starting seed, they create the same sequence every time.

But they are NOT suitable for cryptgraphical purposes, as they produce "random" numbers with very little entropy.